# Does LSB steganography permanently change the pixels of the image?

Tags: ffmpeg, steganography

When you encrypt an image using LSB steganography it alters a few of the pixels. My question is if say you input that image in a video using ffmpeg and re-encode the video plus the image will the pixels still be altered and be able to be decrypted or not?

Comment: The questions in the title and body are asking for two different things. Which one is it?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the compression used during encoding. If it is lossless (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression) the pixels will remain the same, if it is lossy they are very likely to be changed and information is lost.